# How do I show that M1, M2 are two Turing machines such that L(M1) ⊆ L(M2)?

Tags: turing-machines, automata

I am currently studying for a midterm tomorrow and my professor gave us links to backtests online. This is problem #3 in the following back quiz:

http://www.myoops.org/cocw/mit/NR/rdonlyres/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-045JAutomata--Computability--and-ComplexitySpring2002/5C8B3587-B7B6-4D5B-A285-06F6551E9D27/0/quiz2.pdf

I am thinking that we need to construct a second turing machine to enumerate certain strings to prove the subsets, but I do not know where to start. I also cannot find a proof online anywhere that is similar to this. If someone can point me towards the right direction so that I can understand this concept, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: you can encode the Halting problem inside the language because it is possible to express "machine $M$ halts" in the form $L(M_1) \subseteq L(M_2)$ for suitably chosen $M_1$ and $M_2$ (they depend on $M$ but in a computable way).

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  We prefer that questions be self-contained.  Please edit the question to include the problem in your post (use Latex to typeset mathematics; don't just use an image), and make sure to acknowledge your original source.  The original source for the quiz is here: http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.045/spring02/handouts/ho10.pdf.  You should be crediting MIT course 6-045, Spring 2002, Prof. Ron Rivest.  Also tell us what approaches you've considered so far and specifically is preventing you from making progress (what concept are you unclear on?).

Comment: Meta hint: if your exam is tomorrow and you face a problem you "do not know where to start" with, that's a big sign that you did something very wrong for half the term.

Comment: Hint: reduce the problem to one you know to be undecidable by fixing either $M_1$ or $M_2$ to some well-chosen constant.